# Output index with Select-Object

Tags: powershell

Using one of the overloads of the LINQ `Select` method, I can construct a new type with the index of the item as one of the properties:

```
var lst = new List<int>() {1,1,2,3,5};
var selected = lst.Select((x,index) => new {
    number = x,
    index
});
```

Is it possible to also include the current index as one of the properties of the output object using `Select-Object`?

```
# $selected.Visual is a WPF Grid
$selected.Visual.ColumnDefinitions | Select-Object -Property Width, MinWidth, MaxWidth, ActualWidth
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you can access the index but you can pipe the output to the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet and calculate the index yourself:

```
$selected.Visual.ColumnDefinitions | ForEach-Object -Begin {$idx = 0} -Process {
    $_ | Select-Object Width, MinWidth, MaxWidth, ActualWidt, @{l='index'; e={$idx}}
    $idx += 1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is using a variable which autoincrements so there is no need for a loop:

```
$index = 0
$selected.Visual.ColumnDefinitions | Select-Object -Property @{n="index";e={(++$Script:index)}}, Width, MinWidth, MaxWidth, ActualWidt
```

The script scope modifier is necessary for updating the value of index.

Comment: Brilliant !!!  Note to self: The syntax of the computed expression is important.  Don't forget the surrounding parenthesizes "()" and "$Script:"  (++$Script:index)